# Android app authentication with Microsoft account

Tags: android

I am just trying to create an login activity with microsoft. This is my code....

```
package com.example.microsoft_login;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Arrays;
import com.microsoft.live.LiveAuthException;
import com.microsoft.live.LiveAuthListener;
import com.microsoft.live.LiveAuthClient;
import com.microsoft.live.LiveConnectSession;
import com.microsoft.live.LiveConnectClient;
import com.microsoft.live.LiveStatus;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LiveAuthListener {

    private LiveAuthClient auth;
    private LiveConnectClient client;
    private TextView resultTextView;    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.resultTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
        this.auth = new LiveAuthClient(this, MyConstants.APP_CLIENT_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Iterable<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("wl.signin", "wl.basic");
        this.auth.login(null, scopes, this);
    }

    public void onAuthComplete(LiveStatus status, LiveConnectSession session, Object userState) {
        if(status == LiveStatus.CONNECTED) {
            this.resultTextView.setText("Signed in.");
            client = new LiveConnectClient(session);
        }
        else {
            this.resultTextView.setText("Not signed in.");
            client = null;
        }        
    }

    public void onAuthError(LiveAuthException exception, Object userState) {
        this.resultTextView.setText("Error signing in: " + exception.getMessage());        
        client = null;        
    }
}
```

But it shows.....Unfortunately App has stopped.And the Logcat shows.........

09-13 00:35:50.128: D/AndroidRuntime(2488): Shutting down VM
09-13 00:35:50.168: W/dalvikvm(2488): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.microsoft_login/com.example.microsoft_login.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input parameter 'activity' is invalid. 'activity' cannot be null.
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input parameter 'activity' is invalid. 'activity' cannot be null.
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488):     at com.microsoft.live.LiveConnectUtils.assertNotNull(LiveConnectUtils.java:31)
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488):     at com.microsoft.live.LiveAuthClient.login(LiveAuthClient.java:409)
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488):     at com.microsoft.live.LiveAuthClient.login(LiveAuthClient.java:384)
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488):     at com.example.microsoft_login.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:32)
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5143)
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
09-13 00:35:50.200: E/AndroidRuntime(2488):     ... 11 more
09-13 01:10:22.488: D/AndroidRuntime(2699): Shutting down VM
09-13 01:10:22.488: W/dalvikvm(2699): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.microsoft_login/com.example.microsoft_login.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input parameter 'activity' is invalid. 'activity' cannot be null.
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input parameter 'activity' is invalid. 'activity' cannot be null.
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699):     at com.microsoft.live.LiveConnectUtils.assertNotNull(LiveConnectUtils.java:31)
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699):     at com.microsoft.live.LiveAuthClient.login(LiveAuthClient.java:409)
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699):     at com.microsoft.live.LiveAuthClient.login(LiveAuthClient.java:384)
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699):     at com.example.microsoft_login.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:32)
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5143)
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
09-13 01:10:22.598: E/AndroidRuntime(2699):     ... 11 more
09-13 01:10:30.678: I/Process(2699): Sending signal. PID: 2699 SIG: 9
09-13 01:25:16.060: D/AndroidRuntime(2850): Shutting down VM
09-13 01:25:16.060: W/dalvikvm(2850): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.microsoft_login/com.example.microsoft_login.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input parameter 'activity' is invalid. 'activity' cannot be null.
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input parameter 'activity' is invalid. 'activity' cannot be null.
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850):     at com.microsoft.live.LiveConnectUtils.assertNotNull(LiveConnectUtils.java:31)
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850):     at com.microsoft.live.LiveAuthClient.login(LiveAuthClient.java:409)
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850):     at com.microsoft.live.LiveAuthClient.login(LiveAuthClient.java:384)
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850):     at com.example.microsoft_login.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:32)
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5143)
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
09-13 01:25:16.088: E/AndroidRuntime(2850):     ... 11 more
09-13 01:30:16.614: I/Process(2850): Sending signal. PID: 2850 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0):

it's been a while since you posted this, so i'm not sure if you still need help, but it seems your error is on this line (in your onStart()):

this.auth.login(null, scopes, this);

if you replace the null with "this", that should fix the problem.

```
auth.login(this, scopes, this);
```

the login method from microsoft is as below:

public void login(Activity activity, Iterable scopes, LiveAuthListener listener) {
    this.login(activity, scopes, listener, null);

and requires an activity (where it will draw itself).  in your code snippet, you provided null to it.