# Android: com.microsoft.live signing on to OneDrive

Tags: android, onedrive

I've followed this [Signing users in to OneDrive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dn631821.aspx) and I've seen this [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780505/android-app-authentication-with-microsoft-account) but my app still crashes. How do I sign on to OneDrive on an android app without it crashing?

I've followed this [Signing users in to OneDrive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dn631821.aspx) and I've seen this [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780505/android-app-authentication-with-microsoft-account) but my app still crashes. How do I sign on to OneDrive on an android app without it crashing?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.microsoft.live.LiveAuthClient;
import com.microsoft.live.LiveAuthException;
import com.microsoft.live.LiveAuthListener;
import com.microsoft.live.LiveConnectClient;
import com.microsoft.live.LiveConnectSession;
import com.microsoft.live.LiveStatus;

public class Main extends Activity implements LiveAuthListener {

    private LiveAuthClient auth;
    private LiveConnectClient client;
    private TextView resultTextView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.resultTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
        this.auth = new LiveAuthClient(this, MyConstants.APP_CLIENT_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Iterable<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("wl.signin", "wl.basic");
        this.auth.login(this, scopes, this);
    }

    public void onAuthComplete(LiveStatus status, LiveConnectSession session, Object userState) {
        if(status == LiveStatus.CONNECTED) {
            this.resultTextView.setText("Signed in.");
            client = new LiveConnectClient(session);
        }
        else {
            this.resultTextView.setText("Not signed in.");
            client = null;
        }        
    }

    public void onAuthError(LiveAuthException exception, Object userState) {
        this.resultTextView.setText("Error signing in: " + exception.getMessage());        
        client = null;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste here the crash log